# ORACLE 10g form. check if value entering exists in database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

**Question 1 :**

while inserting how will you check whether the value you entered in that textbox does matched with that in the database.
My example and approach not working. error displayed is:

> table, view does not allow in this context.

`when button pressed[Add button]`

```
//blockname            compare     //database table DRINK, column drink_id
IF (:RESERVATION_BLOCK.DRINK_ID<>DRINK.DRINK_ID) THEN
MESSAGE('IF PART');
ELSE
MESSAGE('ELSE PART'); 
END IF;
```

**QUESTION 2:**

Using if statement to add in database
not working error displayed is when button pressed trigger raised

> unhandled exception ORA-00001.

My example not working: when button pressed [SAVE button] code works perfectly without if statement but that's not a good practice when having null

```
IF (:RESERVATION_BLOCK.DRINK_ID is null) THEN
 MESSAGE('No Drink Ordered');
ELSIF (:RESERVATION_MENU_DRINK_BLOCK.DRINK_ID is not null) THEN
  INSERT INTO RESERVATION_DRINK
  VALUES(
  :RESERVATION_BLOCK.RESERVATION_ID, //comes from previous tab pane block
  :RESERVATION_MENU_DRINK_BLOCK.DRINK_ID,
  :RESERVATION_MENU_DRINK_BLOCK.QUANTITY);
  COMMIT;
  MESSAGE('DRINK ORDER SAVED SUCCESSFULLY!');
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the question: you can't reference table in `IF`, do it *before* it:

```
DECLARE
   l_cnt  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO l_cnt
     FROM drink d
    WHERE d.drink_id = :reservation_block.drink_id;

   IF l_cnt > 0
   THEN
      MESSAGE ('That ID exists');
   ELSE
      MESSAGE ('That ID does not exist');
   END IF;
END;
```

---

As of your second question: `ORA-00001` means that you tried to insert a **duplicate** value which is restricted by unique index (might be a primary or unique key constraint).

What to do?

- fix the `ID` value; I don't have how you populated it into the block, but you did it *wrong*. Consider using a sequence so that Oracle would make sure that values are always unique
- modify the constraint; maybe it has to be composite (having two or more columns, not just the `ID`)
- probably the most stupid solution, but - it *is* a solution, after all: drop the unique constraint

Comment: you are right dear, i have solved the second one very good. thank. now am doing the first one to check whether exist or not

Comment: what if for the first part,  check whether drinkName in textbox is found in database Drink column Drink_Name what will be the code then ?

Comment: You'd use different column (and field) names (i.e. DRINK_NAME instead of DRINK_ID).